# How to correctly pass the Cyrillic alphabet in a post request? Groovy

Tags: groovy

It is not possible to correctly transfer the Cyrillic alphabet to the post request. Letters are replaced with question marks.

Everything works well with numbers and the Latin alphabet.

```
name = 'иии.docx'
multipartRequestEntity.addPart('filename', new StringBody(name)) // return '???.docx'

name = 'fff.docx'
multipartRequestEntity.addPart('filename', new StringBody(name)) // return 'fff.docx'
```

How to correctly pass the Cyrillic alphabet in a post request?

Answer (score 0):

Try by create the String with encoding, something like this:

```
name = new String('иии.docx', 'UTF-8')
```

Also, verify if the `multipartRequestEntity` has any method to set the encoding on the output.

Comment: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.String(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Try by using the constant `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of the String